# L2 Regularization must be added into cost function when using Linear Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, regularized

**L2 Regularization must be added into cost function when using Linear Regression?**

Im not adding l2 or taking into account when computing cost. Is that wrong?

The code snippet below should be sufficient :

```
def gradient(self, X, Y, alpha, minibatch_size):

    predictions = None

    for batch in self.iterate_minibatches(X, Y, minibatch_size, shuffle=True):
        x, y = batch
        predictions = x.dot(self.theta)

        for it in range(self.theta.size):
            temp = x[:, it]
            temp.shape = (y.size, 1)

            errors_x1 = (predictions - y) * temp

            self.theta[it] = self.theta[it] - alpha * (1.0 / y.size) * errors_x1.sum() + self.lambda_l2 * self.theta[it] * self.theta[it].T

    print self.cost(X, Y, self.theta)


def cost(self, X, Y, theta, store=True):
    predictions = X.dot(theta)

    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    cost = mean_squared_error(Y, predictions, sample_weight=None, multioutput='uniform_average')

    if store is True:
        self.cost_history.append(cost)

    return cost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to add L2 (or L1) regularization to your Linear Regression (LR) implementation.

However, adding L2 regularization term to our cost function has an advantage over LR without a regularization term. Most importantly, regularization term helps you to reduce the model overfitting and improve the generalization of your models. LR with L2  regularization is commonly known as  "**Ridge Regression**".

In addition to Ridge Regression, LR with L1 regularization is know as **Lasso Regression**. If you build regression models using Lasso Regression you models would be sparse models. Hence, Lasso can be used for feature selection as well.

Good Luck!

Comment: self.theta[it] = self.theta[it] - alpha * (1.0 / y.size) * errors_x1.sum() + self.lambda_l2 * self.theta[it] * self.theta[it].T